# Q: Piranha CMS - System parameters

Tags: piranha-cms

I have created some custom system parameters in the Piranha CMS
Manager. I like to use those parameters in my code. How do I access
these parameters from my code?

Comment: have you tried anything?

Answer (score 1):

The easiest way is to use the following static method:

```
var val = Piranha.Models.SysParam.GetByName(...);
```

This result of this method is also cached for performance.

Regards

Håkan